# Transfer bitmap from Flash movie to Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I would like to know what is the most efficient way to transfer `BitmapData` object from Actionscript to Javascript, so an image can be displayed on webpage.

So far, I've managed to craft a string containing image data using data URI scheme in Flash and then I transfered it to the Javascript using `ExternalInterface.call("<function_name>", data)`.

While it is working fine, it seems wasteful to convert image to its textual representation just to transfer it. Is there a cleaner/more efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: @wvxvw That's probably not the best way. All modern browsers support the data URI. Given a base64 encoded image, javascript could easily form a value for the src attribute of an image tag that would successfully "load" the encoded image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS3:

base64 encode your BitmapData object. [example](http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2009/12/22/base64-encoding-bitmapdata/)
then:

```
ExternalInterface.call("setImage",encodedImg);
```

Javascript:

```
function setImage(baseSixtyFourEncodedImage)
{
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "data:" + baseSixtyFourEncodedImage;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" src="no_image_from_flash_yet.png">
```

Don't forget to import ExternalInterface on the flash end!
let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, that works but it is hardly different from what I'm using now.

Comment: "So far, I've managed to craft a string containing image data using data URI scheme in Flash and then I transfered it to the Javascript using ExternalInterface.call("<function_name>", data)."

Comment: You could theoretically zip it before hand... I'm not sure how browsers would cope with that though.